# How to access config file without dll?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, app-config

I have 2 projects, lets take project1 and project2 . I have app.config file under project1 containing key "xyz". I can not access it from project2 using dll due to circular reference. Whats another professional approach for the same ?

Comment: What about adding the other project's app.config as a **link**? (Add existing file, click little arrow next to save button, select add as link)

Comment: @Matt: How is it different from Adding as reference? Can you please elaborate? Also any other way possible? Because someone suggested me to pass my one of resource using config file, so willing to follow his approach but being a fresher not sure how to do.

Comment: I mean in project2, add the app.config from project1 as a link. See **Adding an Existing Item as a Link** on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx. Does this meet your needs?

Comment: @Matt: In both the way, adding link or reference, it can create circular reference.

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly the problem is. Are you getting an error message? Compiler error?

Comment: @MattJacobi: Yes it worked Matt. But do you have any other approach ?

Answer (score 0):

It should not create a circular reference, as the config file is not an executable code. Matt Jacobi suggestion should work in your case. Can you describe it more if it does not solve you problem.